# Making a Leaderboard ranking that puts records in SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a ranking system I have no idea how to start, below is a pic of the column "balance"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xipb7.png]

like for the user who has the highest amount of balance his rank will be #1, the user who is below him his rank will be #2 now these rank, I want it to be updated to that column "rank_funds" below is a pic:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Ifu.png]

I know you can arrange the users order by ASC or DESC, but when it gets organized there wont be a rank for each user right? so that's what im trying to do, for each user I need to update his rank as ordered.

may you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daac3/1/0) use a variable

```
SET @rank = 0;
UPDATE t1 SET rank = (@rank := @rank + 1)
ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

my column `rank` would be your column `rank_funds`